# Create an Array of Property Names As Strings - and Their Counts (Js Ts)

Tags: javascript

For some reason this one is getting me.  I started down the reduce way, then failed.  I need to iterate over an array of objects, find a property by name (`target`), find all the unique values for that property, and create an array of those unique values with the number of times they appear.  Here is the data structure.

DATA:

```
[
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "A", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "B", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "C", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "A", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "B", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "C", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "A", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "B", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "A", other: "doesnt matter" }
]
```

What I am aiming for is a new array like this:

```
newArray = [['A', 4], ['B', 3], ['C', 2]]
```

What I kind of had, but doesn't fully work:

```
arr.reduce((accumulator: any, currentOrder: any) => {

  if ( !accumulator[currentOrder[property] ] ) { 
    accumulator[currentOrder[property]] = [];
  }

  accumulator[currentOrder[property]].push(currentOrder);

  return accumulator;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to build an object of counts of each `target` value, then [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) on that object to convert to your desired array format:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "A", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "B", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "C", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "A", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "B", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "C", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "A", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "B", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "A", other: "doesnt matter" }
]

const newArray = Object.entries(Object.values(data)
  .reduce((acc, { target }) => {
    acc[target] = (acc[target] || 0) + 1
    return acc
  }, {})
)

console.log(newArray)
```

This works by iterating the array using `reduce`, which takes as its parameters the accumulator and the current element. We use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to only access the `target` property of the element, since that is all we need. The accumulator is an object with its properties the values of the `target` property of each object in the array and we increment the value for the appropriate `target` each time through the loop. Once we've built this object (which for your sample data looks like `{ 'A' : 4, 'B' : 3, 'C' : 2 }` we use Object.entries to convert that to an array of arrays of key/value pairs i.e. `[ [ "A", 4 ], [ "B", 3 ], [ "C", 2 ] ]`

Comment: could you expand on your answer a bit?  I am trying to walk-through it, but not fully getting all the functionality.  I am 93% following it lol.

Comment: @RooksStrife sorry about slow reply - had to do some work! Please see my edit, hopefully that will help.

Comment: thanks - it was the object destructuring that got me.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following `forEach` function. It can iterate and produce the thing you need.

```
var json = data //your data here 
result = {};
  
json.forEach(function(v){
  !result[v.target] ? result[v.target] = 1 : result[v.target] += 1;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty easy. Just

```
function frequencyCountsByTarget( arr ) {
  return Object
         .entries(
           arr.reduce(
             (acc,o) -> acc[o.target] = 1 + ( acc[o.target] ?? 0 ),
             {}
         )
         .sort( (x,y) => x[0] < y[0] ? -1 : x[0] > y[0] ? +1 : 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a Map class, similar to the Map class featured in java.
Take this custom Map class for example:

```
// To Get: [['A', 4], ['B', 3], ['C', 2]]
class Map {
  keys = [] // List of Keys
  vals = [] // List of Vals
  constructor() {
    
  }

  getKeys() {
    return(this.keys) // Return the list of all stored keys
  }

  containsKey(k) {
    return(this.keys.includes(k));
  }

  put(k, v) {
    if (this.keys.includes(k)) { // Key already exists
      this.vals.splice(this.keys.indexOf(k), 1, v) // Replace the old val with the new val
      return(false) // Return false, if value already existed
    }
    else { // Key needs to be added
      this.keys.push(k) // Add to keys
      this.vals.push(v) // Add to vals
      return(true) // Return true, if new value created
    }
  }

  get(k) {
    if (this.keys.includes(k)) {
      return(this.vals[this.keys.indexOf(k)]) // Return if key exists
    }
    return(null) // Return null if non-existant
  }

  remove(k) {
    if (this.keys.includes(k)) {
      this.vals.splice(this.keys.indexOf(k), 1) // Remove from vals
      this.keys.splice(this.keys.indexOf(k), 1) // Remove from keys
      return(true) // Return true if removed
    }
    return(false) // Return false if didn't exist
  }
}
```

To use the Map to count or store your elements in some way, you could have your code such as this:

```
data = [
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "A", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "B", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "C", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "A", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "B", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "C", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "A", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "B", other: "doesnt matter" },
  { name: "doesnt matter", target: "A", other: "doesnt matter" }
]

const map = new Map(); // Create empty map

for (element of data) {
  if (map.containsKey(element.target)) { // Map contains the target
    map.put(element.target, map.get(element.target)+1) // Replace the value with the old + 1
  }
  else { // Map doesn't contain the target
    map.put(element.target, 1) // Default number
  }
}

console.log("["+map.keys+"] --> ["+map.vals+"]") // Simple way to print

for (key of map.getKeys()) { // Loop through all added keys
  console.log(key+" ~ "+map.get(key)) // Display the values
}
```

What it does, is it stores keys and corresponding values to two different lists without storing duplicate keys. Any repeated keys get their value changed or set to the most recently `put` value.

Your list of objects can then be anything from a custom class, to HTML elements, and even your `data` elements. The values could then be stored as a count or a list of matching values.

Just loop through a list using a for loop, and add the target property to your map, adding to or changing the corresponding value each time.

Answer (score 0):

This code reduces the input data to an object that holds the count of the values stored in the key called `target`.

```js
data = [
    { name: "doesnt matter", target: "A", other: "doesnt matter" },
    { name: "doesnt matter", target: "B", other: "doesnt matter" },
    { name: "doesnt matter", target: "C", other: "doesnt matter" },
    { name: "doesnt matter", target: "A", other: "doesnt matter" },
    { name: "doesnt matter", target: "B", other: "doesnt matter" },
    { name: "doesnt matter", target: "C", other: "doesnt matter" },
    { name: "doesnt matter", target: "A", other: "doesnt matter" },
    { name: "doesnt matter", target: "B", other: "doesnt matter" },
    { name: "doesnt matter", target: "A", other: "doesnt matter" }
  ]

let count = data.reduce(
    (counterObject, element) => {
        let currentKey = element.target;
        if (!Object.keys(counterObject).includes(currentKey)) {
            counterObject[currentKey] = 1;
            return counterObject;
        }
        counterObject[currentKey]++;
        return counterObject;
    }, {}
);

console.log(count);
```

The reduce function checks if the key already exists in the counterObject. If not adds a new key to it with the value `1`. Otherwise it increases the count of the current key.

If you need the exact format with the nested arrays you could apply this code afterwards:

```
let countArray = []
for(let key of Object.keys(count)) {
    countArray.push([key, count[key]]);
}
```